# Adding an Animated Heart Icon to Current Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, react-native-animatable

I am making an animated heart icon in my react native app. Currently, I have a generic `Button` which accepts an `icon` prop, letting it display an icon:

```
<Button
  color="white"
  icon={selected ? (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="selected" size={24} />) : 
  (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="unselected" size={24} />)}
  onPress={async () => {
    const newSelectedStates = [...selectedStates];
    newSelectedStates[index] = !selected;
    setSelectedStates(newSelectedStates);
    // make some API requests with the async behavior
}}
/>
```

So currently, I have multiple buttons. The states of whether these icons are selected or not is held in a parent array. In the above code, `selected` is one element from that array, corresponding to the relevant button.

When I click the button, it edits the state array, therefore rendering a new icon.

What I would like to do is add an animated heart when I click the button, rather than simply rendering one of two icons based on the state. It seems like good design to have something reusable and DRY. I believe having an external component, `AnimatedHeart`, which accepts a `selected` prop is the way to go. However, I am not sure on how I can handle the `onPress` functionality to also animate the heart itself?

For instance, if I define an animated heart component, and include an `onPress` inside it, I now have to juggle two `onPress`'s which seems like poor design.

Does anyone know how I can seamlessly link these two together? I'm less interested in the actual heart animation itself, and more on getting everything working. I'm also not keen on creating the `onPress` for the heart animation at the parent level because that seems less reusable. I feel it would be better to have the animation encapsulated within the heart component itself.

I may need two `onPress`'s though ultimately, since each button click should do a unique thing (for instance a different API call), and the heart press should be consistent